# How do you use scanf to read user input and create a string from what the user types?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am very new to programming and I am struggling trying to connect pointers with arrays and strings.

```
int scanString();
int main(void)
{
   char string[] = {};
   scanString(string);
}

int scanString(char * string)
{
   printf("Enter a string without spaces and hit enter: ");
   scanf("%s", string);
   int length = sizeof(*string);
   for(int i=0;i<length;++i){
      printf("%c", string[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I fixed how I was calling the function from main and now I no longer have a segmentation fault but now it is only printing out the first letter of the string that I input because I am doing `int length = sizeof(*string)` which is only a single character. I am confused on how to correctly declare `int length` to match the length of the string that I input.

Comment: What do you want to do? `length = sizeof(string);` is bad because `sizeof(string)` is not the length of string but the size of the pointer `char*` and `const char string[length] = *string;` is bad because 1. The name `string` is already used as the argument. 2. The number of elements is wrong: there are no room for terminating null-character (if you want to use the array as string) 3. you cannot initialize arrays like this. You should use `memcpy()` (if you won't treat the data as string) or `strcpy()` (if you will treat the data as string: increasing the number of elements is required).

Comment: The `%s` specifier of `scanf()` will have it create string from user input. No manual thing will be required.

Comment: @MikeCAT I made some changes and it now compiles but I am getting a segmentation fault after I enter the string. I did not use `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` because my professor has not mentioned those yet so I do not know how to use them. Is there a way to do it without that?

Comment: @ColbyWilliams, add the main function to the post, without it we can only guess, I have a feeling that you are passing uninitialized arguments to the function.

Comment: `length = sizeof(*string);` is sttill wrong, that is the size of a single character.

Comment: The expression `sizeof(*string)` will give you the length of a single character, because `*` is the dereference operator and dereferencing `string`, which is a `char*`, will give you a `char`. If you want to set `length` to the length of the string pointed to by the pointer `string`, then you will have to write `strlen( string )` instead. So you should replace `int length = sizeof(*string);` with `int length = strlen( string );`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find out the length of an string in C is to iterate through it all, until you reach the end.

In C, the end of a string is marked by a null character, which can be escaped as `'\0'`.

Knowing this, we can write the following code:

```
int length = 0;
while (string[length] != '\0')
    length++;
```

The above code iterates through the whole string, character by character, incrementing the length until it finds a null character. When the loop exits, you end with the length of the string stored in the `length` variable.

Note: There is a function called `strlen` (prototyped in the `string.h` header file) which does just this.